# OS X give focus to a window after showing

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I have noticed something that really annoys me.
Say I have some applications running and then I select a particular one using Dock. This application appears on the screen but does not receive focus (windows is displayed as inactive). So, when I type something input is not going to the foremost window.

For more clarification I can say that I always encounter this when focusing Terminal app that is not maximized - window is shown, but no focus on it. Moreover, when I click on an app icon in the Dock and this app was maximized, I have to click twice to see this app.

Have anyone encountered the same?

**UPD**: the problem relates to switching from full-screen app to non full-screen and vice versa. Switching from one full screen app to another full screen app or from one non-full screen to another non-full screen does not reproduce the problem

Comment: It's something I've noticed occasionally happens - used to be more so on Mavericks. Try killing the Dock `killall -KILL Dock` & check again.

Comment: It seems that it didn't help.

Comment: Does rebooting restore the correct behaviour?

Comment: It seems that not :(

Comment: Then I'd check it in the guest account or make a new admin account & test there.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've created a new admin account, it worked fine there. After I switched back to my account it also worked fine for some time. Later, problem came  back

Comment: That leaves the likelihood that it's something running on one account only. The difficult bit is going to be... figuring out what.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tested in safe mode, problem is still there. It seems that it is not caused by an application that starts at system startup.

Comment: Finally I've solved this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution myself. In system settings on the Mission Control tab the second option of the top group must be checked. I don't know exactly how it is in English, it shall be something like 'Switch to space with application windows when switching to an application' or something like that.

I used [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15701122#15701122) as a tip, it says about the third checkbox, but in my case the second one has solved my trouble.

Comment: It reads "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application." You should update your question to make it clear that this has to do only with apps/windows in different spaces.

Comment: I do not agree. I do not use spaces at all, so my problem is not related to them, but ticking this checkbox solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I would also take a look at bettertouchtool although january 2016 is the last month it will be freeware. I believe it has an option for it

Comment: I'm not sure that I need to use external app for the behavior that should be build-in.

Comment: True that, however it was a thought that came up. Delete this answer if u see fit